# Java Vector of Object and Sort/Group by third value

Tags: java, sorting, collections, grouping, comparator

I have a Vector of customers:

```
Vector<Customer> customers = Vector<Customer>();
```

Customer looks like:

```
public class Customer {

   private String firstName;
   private String lastName;
   private Customer partner;
}
```

Sample data:

1. Peter; Doe; Gloria Ven
2. John, Doe, null
3. Gloria; Ven; Peter Doe
4. Jonny; Tab; null

I would like to sort this vector by grouping the partners together. So the result should look like this:

1. Peter; Doe; Gloria Ven
2. Gloria; Ven; Peter Doe
3. John, Doe, null
4. Jonny; Tab; null

Any ideas how do I do this efficiently?

First I tried to solve this by using a custom Sort function (for collections) by overwriting the compare-Method.
The problem is that I just did it when comparing the same field.
In this case I have to compare basically something like this "this.compareTo(getPartner().getPartner());" but I couldn't get in running.

Second try would be obviously looping over the vector over and over again manually and sort it "by hand" and I would prefer to avoid that, because I thought its a common problem and someone already came up with a better solution.

Thank you!

Comment: You also shouldn't be using `Vector`, for the reasons described in detail in its documentation.

Comment: Updated with the things I came up so far, it wasn't much, therefore I didn't wrote it in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Note: class `Vector` is obsolete and may be replaced with other implementations of `List` interface like `ArrayList`.*

Simpler sorting may be applied by placing the customers without the partners to the end with the help of `nullsLast` comparator.

Let's assume we have the following test data:

```java
Customer a = new Customer("Peter", "Doe");
Customer x = new Customer("Gloria", "Ven", a);
Customer b = new Customer("Adam", "Swan");
Customer z = new Customer("Mary", "Blake", b);
Customer p = new Customer("John", "Doe");
Customer y = new Customer("Kyle", "Flint");

List<Customer> data = Arrays.asList(a, b, p, x, y, z);

// a Vector may be created similarly
// Vector<Customer> data = new Vector<>(Arrays.asList(a, b, p, x, y, z));

Collections.shuffle(data);
System.out.println(data);
```

Then custom comparators `byLastAndFirst` and `byPartnerLastAndFirst` are implemented and applied to `partner` field and then self customer.

```
Comparator<Customer> byLastAndFirst = Comparator.comparing(Customer::getLastName)
        .thenComparing(Customer::getFirstName);

Comparator<Customer> byPartnerLastAndFirst = Comparator
    .comparing(Customer::getPartner, Comparator.nullsLast(byLastAndFirst))
    .thenComparing(byLastAndFirst);

data.sort(byPartnerLastAndFirst);
System.out.println(data);
```

This provides the following results:

```java
[`Adam Swan` & `Mary Blake`, `Gloria Ven` & `Peter Doe`, `Mary Blake` & `Adam Swan`, `Peter Doe` & `Gloria Ven`, `John Doe` & NULL, `Kyle Flint` & NULL]
```

However, the partners are not grouped together in this solution.

Additional grouping can be implemented with Stream API by collecting the customers into a sorted map where a key is a sorted list of a customer and a partner, the partner may be `null`, and then the keys of the map are mapped back to list of the customers using `Stream::flatMap` and excluding `null` partners:

```java
Comparator<List<Customer>> sort = Comparator.comparing(list -> list.get(0), byPartnerLastAndFirst);

data.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        c -> Arrays.asList(c, c.getPartner())
                .stream()
                .sorted(Comparator.nullsLast(byLastAndFirst))
                .collect(Collectors.toList()),
        () -> new TreeMap<>(sort),
        Collectors.toList()
    ))
    .keySet().stream() // Stream<List<Customer>>
    .flatMap(list -> list.stream().filter(Objects::nonNull))
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Output (may be improved to not show NULL partners)

```
`Mary Blake` & `Adam Swan`
`Adam Swan` & `Mary Blake`
`Peter Doe` & `Gloria Ven`
`Gloria Ven` & `Peter Doe`
`John Doe` & NULL
`Kyle Flint` & NULL
```